# FuelPHP 302 Redirects on Heroku

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, heroku, fuelphp

Heroku is throwing repeated 302 redirects for all urls going to the base URL, and I don't know why. Everything works fine locally on my dev server.

Procfile:

```
web: fuel/vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 web/
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

    # Remove index.php from URL
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With}    !^XMLHttpRequest$
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}              ^[^/]*/index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$            $1 [R=301,NS,L]

    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ index.php/$1 [L]

    # make HTTP Basic Authentication work on php5-fcgi installs
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    </IfModule>

    # Send request via index.php if not a real file or directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # deal with php5-cgi first
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_fcgid.c>

        # for normal Apache installations
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
        </IfModule>

        # for Apache FGCI installations
        <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>

    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Pages that actually exist get loaded.

404s work correctly, loading a 404 page:

```
2015-11-04T19:13:55.489566+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/test/" host=my.url request_id=b4c4853b-69fe-444e-b03b-5eea7c10b018 fwd="73.218.177.115" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=15ms status=404 bytes=6156
```

Locations that should "exist" by being redirected to FuelPHP get redirected down to the base URL..
I try to load my.url/admin or my.url/admin/clients and I'm redirected to my.url.

```
2015-11-04T19:14:08.858400+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/" host=my.url request_id=7a16369b-e647-4399-b11d-a1522d9766a7 fwd="73.218.177.115" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=19ms status=302 bytes=1235
2015-11-04T19:14:08.894102+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=my.url request_id=5780087d-0847-40e6-9a44-b0dabd58577e fwd="73.218.177.115" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=205
2015-11-04T19:14:08.854106+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.87.95 - - [04/Nov/2015:19:14:08 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
2015-11-04T19:14:08.889796+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.87.95 - - [04/Nov/2015:19:14:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
2015-11-04T19:14:18.756248+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=my.url request_id=6eb6d76e-9f0c-4be0-b52a-220a459b9c57 fwd="73.218.177.115" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=205
2015-11-04T19:14:18.715333+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.87.95 - - [04/Nov/2015:19:14:18 +0000] "GET /admin/clients/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
2015-11-04T19:14:18.719632+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/clients/" host=my.url request_id=b15304cf-cd01-4cd6-9613-71d332fcc5a4 fwd="73.218.177.115" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=302 bytes=1235
2015-11-04T19:14:18.752065+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.87.95 - - [04/Nov/2015:19:14:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
```

Slightly modified app/classes/controller/admin.php

```
public function action_login()
{
    // Already logged in
    Auth::check() and Response::redirect('admin');

    $val = Validation::forge();

    if (Input::method() == 'POST')
    {
        $val->add('email', 'Email or Username')
            ->add_rule('required');
        $val->add('password', 'Password')
            ->add_rule('required');

        if ($val->run())
        {
            if ( ! Auth::check())
            {
                if (Auth::login(Input::post('email'), Input::post('password')))
                {
                    // assign the user id that lasted updated this record
                    foreach (\Auth::verified() as $driver)
                    {
                        if (($id = $driver->get_user_id()) !== false)
                        {
                            // credentials ok, check access level
                            $user = Model\Auth_User::find($id[1]);

                            // ADDED THIS TO CHECK ADMIN LEVEL ACCESS
                            if ($user->group >= 80) {
                                //logged in! yay!
                                $current_user = $user;
                                Session::set_flash('success', e('Welcome, ' . $current_user->username));
                                Response::redirect('admin');
                            }
                            else {
                                $this->template->set_global('login_error', 'No access!');
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->template->set_global('login_error', 'Login failed!');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->template->set_global('login_error', 'Already logged in!');
            }
        }
    }

    $this->template->title = 'Login';
    $this->template->subtitle = 'See all the things!';
    $this->template->content = View::forge('admin/login', array('val' => $val), false);
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Doesn't Heroku use fcgi? If so, you need different rewrite rules. As I understand the default .htaccess as supplied in the FuelPHP distribution works fine on Heroku.

Comment: You're right. Except I fixed it and it didn't help. :( I did modify a bit of the oil generated admin code to split admin users from normal users. I wonder if that's doing it? Posted code.

Comment: I don't know what you modified, all I can see in the logs that a requesst for /admin gets redirected back to /, which could easily be caused by a Response::redirect() call in your code.

Comment: The only thing I added was "if ($user->group >= 80) {}" around the logged-in code.

I haven't added or changed any Response::redirect() code and everything works just great on my local server. It only doesn't work when pushed to Heroku.